# Visual Studio code : terminated with exit code: 3221225477

Tags: terminal

Just started using Visual Studio code on my laptop ( Windows 10 Home, 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor ) and every time I open the terminal it immediately shuts down and gives me this message:

> "C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" terminated with exit code: 3221225477.

I have no idea what's going and I've already gone to the Visual Studio Terminal troubleshooting page and nothing in there was useful. My legacy console setting is not enabled.

(Also it has nothing to do with my anti virus, I just took to the best buy that installed it for me and they made sure none of the settings or directories impacted VS Code).

Comment: How do you try to open PowerShell? Can you open it through the Start menu?
"help me with this asap" - that is a no-no here. You are not entitled to anybody's time here unless you plan to pay them.

Comment: are you familiar with this problem ? Would i be able to fix it by changing the PowerShell ?

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstalling it and reinstalling it, make sure all system drivers are up to date etc.

Comment: i just did im still getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

See [PowerShell in Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/powershell)  to solve your problem.

You must install the PowerShell extension on VS!

Comment: Link only answers are not much useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an alternative method,
Right click the mouse and select "run current file in interactive windows"

[image]